# Uploading additional metadata as part of file upload request to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: file-upload, httprequest, metadata, google-cloud-storage, multipart

I tried a lot to get this thing done but all in vain.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert) is complete documentation

[Link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-javascript-samples) to JavaScript code base

If I try Google's online [tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert#try-it) to upload file then it successfully creates whatever metadata I supply. I am not sure what different they are doing. Unfortunately, I can't even figure it out.

My latest code base to upload a file along with metadata

> function insertObject(event) {
>
> ```
>   try{
>     var fileData = event.target.files[0];
>   } 
>   catch(e) {
>     //'Insert Object' selected from the API Commands select list
>     //Display insert object button and then exit function
>     filePicker.style.display = 'block';
>     return;
>   }
>
>   const boundary = 'hoho314159265358979323846';
>   const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
>   const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";
>
>   var reader = new FileReader();
>   reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
>   reader.onload = function(e) {
>     var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
>     var metadata = {          
>           'name': fileData.name,
>           'mimeType': contentType,
>           'test': contentType             
>     };
>
>      var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
>     var multipartRequestBody =
>       delimiter +
>       'Content-Type: application/json; \r\n\r\n' +
>       JSON.stringify(metadata) +
>       delimiter +
>       'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
>       'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
>       '\r\n' +
>       base64Data +
>       close_delim;
>
>     //Note: gapi.client.storage.objects.insert() can only insert
>     //small objects (under 64k) so to support larger file sizes
>     //we're using the generic HTTP request method gapi.client.request()
>     var request = gapi.client.request({
>       'path': '/upload/storage/' + API_VERSION + '/b/' + BUCKET + '/o',
>       'method': 'POST',
>       'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
>       'headers': {
>         'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
>       },
>       'body': multipartRequestBody});
>       //Remove the current API result entry in the main-content div
>       listChildren = document.getElementById('main-content').childNodes;
>       if (listChildren.length > 1) {
>         listChildren[1].parentNode.removeChild(listChildren[1]);
>       }
>     try{
>       //Execute the insert object request
>       executeRequest(request, 'insertObject');
>       //Store the name of the inserted object 
>       object = fileData.name;   
>     }
>     catch(e) {
>       alert('An error has occurred: ' + e.message);
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

I have read multipart [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload?&_ga=1.60065834.682709677.1431352655#multipart) and tried to do the same thing but no help.

If I create metadata (in json format) like following then it throws error code 400 saying object required otherwise it uploads file but not metadata.

var metadata = {
  'metadata': {
    'customerName': 'Sigma1',
    'model': 'xvrt56',
    'issue': 'loud sound'
   }
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot but unable to add metadata as part of initial file upload request. I ended up sending metadata in another 'patch' request. Please let me know if you have a better solution

```
/**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to insert an object into
     * your Google Cloud Storage bucket.
     */
    function insertObject(fileControl, metadata, callBack) {
        debugger;
      try{
        var fileData = fileControl.files[0];
      } 
      catch(e) {
        //'Insert Object' selected from the API Commands select list
        //Display insert object button and then exit function
        //filePicker.style.display = 'block';
        return;
      }
      const boundary = 'hoho314159265358979323846';
      const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
      const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

      var fileName = metadata.name;

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
        var metadata1 = {
          'name': fileName,
          'mimeType': contentType
        };

        var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
        var multipartRequestBody =
          delimiter + 
          'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 \r\n\r\n' +
          JSON.stringify(metadata1) +
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
          'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
          '\r\n' +
          base64Data +
          close_delim;

        //Note: gapi.client.storage.objects.insert() can only insert
        //small objects (under 64k) so to support larger file sizes
        //we're using the generic HTTP request method gapi.client.request()
        var request = gapi.client.request({
          'path': '/upload/storage/' + API_VERSION + '/b/' + PCSING_BUCKET + '/o',
          'method': 'POST',
          'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
          'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
          },
          'body': multipartRequestBody});

        try{
          //Execute the insert object request
             request.execute(function(resp) {               

             multipartRequestBody = {                
                  'metadata': metadata
             }  

             request = gapi.client.request({
              'path': '/storage/' + API_VERSION + '/b/' + PCSING_BUCKET + '/o/' + fileName,
              'method': 'PATCH',                  
              'body': multipartRequestBody
              });

              //https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/object

            request.execute(function(resp) {
                callBack();
                console.log(resp);
            });

         });

          //Store the name of the inserted object 
          //object = fileData.name;   
        }
        catch(e) {
          alert('An error has occurred: ' + e.message);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this one without finding a good resource, so it was all trial and error.

The answer appears to be putting the additional metadata in a metadata key:

```
var metadata1 = {
    metadata: fileData.metadata,
    'name': fileData.name,
    'mimeType': contentType
};
```

Sorta meta