# Uploading an image to Google Cloud storage from webpage

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the documentation Google have provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-javascript-samples) to try to upload images from a webpage to Google Cloud storage. I think the storage has been set up correctly and I think I've gotten the correct values.

When used, the image is recognised, but for some reason it's not uploading. I'm unsure whether it's the code or how the environment is set up. Also, no error messages are being reported. I know the image is going into the function through the event.

The javascript is...

```
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to insert an object into
         * your Google Cloud Storage bucket.
         */
        function insertObject(event) {
            try {
                //var MyFile = document.getElementById("take-picture").files;
                var fileData = event.target.files[0];
                //var fileData = document.getElementById("take-picture").files;
            } 
            catch(e) {
                //'Insert Object' selected from the API Commands select list
                //Display insert object button and then exit function
                //filePicker.style.display = 'block';
                return;
            }
          var boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
          var delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
          var close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
                var metadata = {
                    'name': fileData.name,
                    'mimeType': contentType
                };

                var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
                var multipartRequestBody =
                  delimiter +
                  'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
                  JSON.stringify(metadata) +
                  delimiter +
                  'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
                  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
                  '\r\n' +
                  base64Data +
                  close_delim;

                //Note: gapi.client.storage.objects.insert() can only insert
                //small objects (under 64k) so to support larger file sizes
                //we're using the generic HTTP request method gapi.client.request()
                var request = gapi.client.request({
                    'path': '/upload/storage/' + API_VERSION + '/b/' + BUCKET + '/o',
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
                    'headers': {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
                    },
                    'body': multipartRequestBody});
                //Remove the current API result entry in the main-content div
                //listChildren = document.getElementById('main-content').childNodes;
                //if (listChildren.length > 1) {
                //    listChildren[1].parentNode.removeChild(listChildren[1]);
                //} 

                //look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317797/uploading-additional-metadata-as-part-of-file-upload-request-to-google-cloud-sto

                try{
                    //Execute the insert object request
                    executeRequest(request, 'insertObject');
                    //Store the name of the inserted object 
                    object = fileData.name;         
                }
                catch(e) {
                    alert('An error has occurred: ' + e.message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you invoke `.then()` or `.catch()` on the result of `client.request(...)`? AFAIK if you do not, the GAPI client will not actually execute the request.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure where the problem is.

But in my working code, I'm using

```
var metadata = {
    'title': fileData.fileName || fileData.name,
    'parents': [{
    "kind": "drive#fileLink",
            "id": folderId
    }],
    'mimeType': contentType
};
```

So your code may missing the ID of your folder

API Request:

```
var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
        'method': 'POST',
        'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
        },
        'body': multipartRequestBody
});
```

FYR.

Comment: The 'path': '/upload/storage/' + API_VERSION + '/b/' + BUCKET + '/o', contains variables regarding my folder, which would be API_VERSION and BUCKET. I think these are correct (I know the Bucket is, and there's an image in the bucket already which seems to have the API_version v1_Internal, which I'm now using - not tried v2, but may give that a go). At the moment I'm thinking it has to do with Public API Access.