# Trying to upload files from a webpage to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-app-engine, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I've got a website (in asp.net) through which I want users to upload photos to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. The users doing the uploading CAN be authenticated with Google if necessary (though I would prefer it if they weren't - the site is locked down with usernames/passwords/captchas).

Slightly unrelated - the photos in the bucket though have to be visible to everyone, so long as they have the link (some of our clients have IT depts who refuse to allow them to use Google accounts, and we can't change their minds). I would want the link ideally returned when the photo is uploaded.

I have the following Javascript code, which I think should work (basically it's taken from [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-javascript-samples)):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var PROJECT = 'MY_PROJECT';
var clientId = 'MY_CLIENT_ID_ENDING_IN_apps.googleusercontent.com';
var apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write';
//quick question - I've got a photo in the bucket already, and its
//URL points to a v1_internal folder. Would that mean that the API
//version is v1_internal?
var API_VERSION = 'v1';
var BUCKET = 'MY_BUCKET';
var object = "";
//question - when using a specific group, should this read group-blahblah
//or, for instance, owners-blahblah
//or even group-owners-blahblah?
var GROUP = 'group-MY_LONG_GROUP_ID';
//stuck on these next few ones
var ENTITY = 'group-Owners';
var ROLE = 'OWNER';
var ROLE_OBJECT = 'OWNER';

function insertObject(event) {
            try {
                var fileData = event.target.files[0];
            } 
            catch(e) {
                //'Insert Object' selected from the API Commands select list
                //Display insert object button and then exit function
                //filePicker.style.display = 'block';
                return;
            }
          var boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
          var delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
          var close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
                var metadata = {
                    'name': fileData.name,
                    'mimeType': contentType
                };

                var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
                var multipartRequestBody =
                  delimiter +
                  'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
                  JSON.stringify(metadata) +
                  delimiter +
                  'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
                  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
                  '\r\n' +
                  base64Data +
                  close_delim;

                //Note: gapi.client.storage.objects.insert() can only insert
                //small objects (under 64k) so to support larger file sizes
                //we're using the generic HTTP request method gapi.client.request()
                var request = gapi.client.request({
                    'path': '/upload/storage/' + API_VERSION + '/b/' + BUCKET + '/o',
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
                    'headers': {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
                    },
                    'body': multipartRequestBody});
                //Remove the current API result entry in the main-content div
                //listChildren = document.getElementById('main-content').childNodes;
                //if (listChildren.length > 1) {
                //    listChildren[1].parentNode.removeChild(listChildren[1]);
                //} 

                //look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317797/uploading-additional-metadata-as-part-of-file-upload-request-to-google-cloud-sto

                try{
                    //Execute the insert object request
                    executeRequest(request, 'insertObject');
                    //Store the name of the inserted object 
                    object = fileData.name;         
                }
                catch(e) {
                    alert('An error has occurred: ' + e.message);
                }
            }
        }

</script>
```

Currently, I can execute the function. The file ends up within the function (I've been able to call an alert on the fileData.name). However, it doesn't end up in the bucket, and there's no error message brought up.

Does this code look okay, or is it a problem with how the storage bucket could be set up? And am I using the correct values (or have I formatted them correctly)?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it. For those who have tried using this code and, like me, didn't bother to read it all, Google is using an "authorize" button. Basically, the example code they provided gives you the ability to more or less "attach" the file, then another button which does the actual uploading. I hadn't seen this myself.