# Google Cloud Storage upload request sometimes works, sometimes doesn't - make resumable?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage

A bit of a pickle here. I've got a Google Cloud Storage bucket set up, and a webpage that, probably about 60% of the time, DOES upload a file to the bucket. However, sometimes it doesn't and I don't really know why.

I'm trying this from a mobile handset so it could be the signal. As such, I guess one thing I need to think about is making it resumable (the files themselves aren't big - less than 2mb, but the service we're getting isn't great).

So, how could I make this into a resumable (rather than multipart) upload? And do you think this would solve the issue?

Code below:

```
            function insertObject(event) {
            try {
                var fileData = event.target.files[0];
            } 
            catch(e) {
                return;
            }
          var boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
          var delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
          var close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
                var metadata = {
                    'name': fileData.name,
                    'mimeType': contentType
                };

                var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
                var multipartRequestBody =
                  delimiter +
                  'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
                  JSON.stringify(metadata) +
                  delimiter +
                  'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
                  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
                  '\r\n' +
                  base64Data +
                  close_delim;

                //Note: gapi.client.storage.objects.insert() can only insert
                //small objects (under 64k) so to support larger file sizes
                //we're using the generic HTTP request method gapi.client.request()
                var request = gapi.client.request({
                    'path': '/upload/storage/' + API_VERSION + '/b/' + BUCKET + '/o',
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
                    'headers': {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
                    },
                    'body': multipartRequestBody});
                //Remove the current API result entry in the main-content div
                //listChildren = document.getElementById('main-content').childNodes;
                //if (listChildren.length > 1) {
                //    listChildren[1].parentNode.removeChild(listChildren[1]);
                //} 

                //look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317797/uploading-additional-metadata-as-part-of-file-upload-request-to-google-cloud-sto

                try{
                    //Execute the insert object request
                    //document.getElementById("authorize-button").click();
                    executeRequest(request, 'insertObject');
                    //Store the name of the inserted object
                    document.getElementById("btnUpload").click();
                    object = fileData.name;
                }
                catch(e) {
                    alert('An error has occurred: ' + e.message);
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT - just tried it from my PC and it's uploaded 17 files with no problems - normally it just starts dropping them straight away from the mobile handset. So I think it is a signal issue and making it resumable would do the job.

Comment: Are you setting the files to have a public link? Are you always testing uploading the same files? If so, it *might* be some kind of Cloud Storage caching.

Comment: Yes, the files have to have a public link, and the same files aren't being tested - always a different one.

Comment: Does it show any error on console or on network?

Comment: Note: if your solution to make it resumable worked, please, post what you've done as a self-answer, including the code, and configuration steps, and if no other better solution appear after 48 hours, accept it, helping people that eventually will face the same problem you had.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't quite know how to make it resumable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is embarrassing.

I decided to check that the code was uploading the file correctly, and got rid of the

```
document.getElementById("btnUpload").click();
object = fileData.name;
```

in the final element of the code (the btnUpload does some C# stuff that I do need, but I don't need the object at all). I tried 20 pictures from my mobile handset and, when it would have usually only done about 12, it did all 20 - and a lot more effectively.

So I think the issue is the btnUpload.click that is taking control of the process away from the file transfer before it's finished. I've just got to find a way to incorporate that back into the code without interfering with things.

[Github link](https://github.com/googlearchive/storage-getting-started-javascript/blob/master/index.html)

And just moved the btnUpload.click() from being within the insertobject to the executeRequest (just after where it calls the log). There just seems to be a small problem now, but not with the file upload. The btnUpload stuff gets called where it should, and the rest is simply sorting out the webpage.

Edit - as an aside, in order to cope with the request length being long (for files which are 4mb or more), I added this to the web.config (in the system.web):

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="214748364"/>
```